# Getting error on Sanitizing Get

Tags: php

I Want to allow only `[^a-zA-Z@_.0-9\']` to be accepted for furthur function so i did this. It's working fine but when i tried to run inserting `anything.php`

It started to find the file name and ends with an error. I already escape the unwanted char but still it's giving error !

> I cannot escape dot (.) because many users are using it

```
   $clean = htmlspecialchars(escapeshellcmd(($_GET["name"]),ENT_QUOTES);

    if ( !preg_match( '/[^a-zA-Z@_.0-9\']/', $clean))
     { 
     if(empty($clean)){

    echo "";

    }else{

//function

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: you can use `\w` to shorten this to `[\w^@.']`. It's also almost impossible to tell what you're asking. Are you getting an error, or is it just allowing strings to pass which you *think* should be caught by your validation?

Comment: Lol impossible ? Sorry for my lang. bro I want that when anybody insert the value. the server should allow if string value consist on only A-Z_.@9-0 value if not then give error else proceed to the request

Comment: Then your regex is wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply asking if the string contains one of those characters, anywhere in it. What you mean to ask is, is the string *entirely* composed of *only* those characters. You need to anchor both ends of the regex, and add a quantifier:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z@_.0-9\']*$/
```

The `^` matches the start of a lin, the `$` matches the end of a line, and the `*` says "0 or more".